# How to visualise data with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-visualization

I know how to visualise based on age/gender, but I also want to visualise them based on `offer_successful` column, this column contains `0` and `1`, I want to have a look at how many females in `0` and `1` etc, can someone provide an example or some links that I can have a look? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want exactly to visualize.
What about:

```python
df['gender'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.male == 1 else 0, axis=1)
result = df.groupby(['gender','offer_successful'])['offer_id'].count().reset_index(name='count')
```

This gives the following output (example):

```
gender  offer_successful    count
0       0                   2
        1                   1
1       0                   1
```